# drag drop richfaces

Tags: richfaces

How to drag and drop a inputtext or any other UI component using richfaces?

Answer (score 1):

Read their example [in RichFaces demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/dragSupport.jsf?c=dndParam)